# Difference in behavior between ambiguous base class conversions in Clang and GCC

Tags: c++, c++11

The following prints `-1` in [GCC 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b0560cc056857ca), VC++ but prints `2` in [Clang 3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa2811d570858759):

```c++
template <int n>
struct base { static constexpr int value = n; };

struct A : base<0> { };
struct B : base<1> { };
struct C : base<2> { };

struct D : A, B, C { };

template <int n>
base<n> base_cast(base<n>);

template <typename T, typename B = decltype(base_cast(std::declval<T>()))>
std::integral_constant<int, B::value> f(int);

template <typename T>
std::integral_constant<int, -1> f(...);

constexpr int value = decltype(f<D>(0))::value;

int main()
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

I say clang is incorrect because there are multiple conversions from `D` to `base<n>`: through`A`, `B`, and `C`. The strange thing clang does is that it seems to convert to the *last* base class in its base specifier list.

Is this a bug in Clang? May I have the actual wording from the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clause 4 in the Standard deals with Standard Conversions:

*4.2 [Note: expressions with a given type will be implicitly converted to other types in several contexts:*

— When used as the source expression for an initialization (which includes use as an argument in a function call and use as the expression in a return statement). The type of the entity being initialized is (generally) the destination type. See 8.5, 8.5.3.

—end note ]

4.3 An expression e can be implicitly converted to a type T if and only if the declaration T t=e; is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t (8.5)

Based on this D is convertible to base<0>, base<1> and base<2>.

```
base<0> b0 = D(); //compiles
base<1> b1 = D(); //compiles
base<2> b2 = D(); //compiles
```

Since there are three possible conversions, the call to base_cast should result in an ambiguous call.

The following code snippet:

```
template <int n>
void print_base(base<n>)
{
   std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
...
print_base(D());
```

gives the following error in gcc 4.7.2:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'print_base(D)'
 note: candidate is:
 note: template<int n> void print_base(base<n>)
 note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 note:   'D' is an ambiguous base class of 'base<n>'
```

The error message seem a little off here: 'D' is an ambiguous *"base"* class of base< n >, but it conveys the point.